# Error deploying WCF Client - 'system.servicemodel was not found in SQL Catalog'

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, triggers, clr

I am trying to complete the tutorial from `http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21149/Invoking-a-WCF-Service-from-a-CLR-Trigger` but I am having problems when trying to deploy the client, I get the following error in the Output:

> Deploy error SQL01268: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 6503, Level 16, State 12, Line 1 Assembly 'system.servicemodel, version=3.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089.' was not found in the SQL catalog.

I am using c# 2010, .NET 4.0 and SQL Server Express 10.

I have tried changing the project to use .NET framework 3.0 and 3.5 but I still receive the same error. Does anyone know how to resolve the problem please?

Edit

This might have something to do with errors I get when I try adding the following assemblies to the SQL Server.

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY SMDiagnostics 
FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\SMDiagnostics.dll'
WITH permission_set = UNSAFE
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.Web] 
FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Web.dll'
WITH permission_set = UNSAFE
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.Messaging] 
FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Messaging.dll'
WITH permission_set = UNSAFE
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.IdentityModel] 
FROM 'C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\System.IdentityModel.dll'
WITH permission_set = UNSAFE
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.IdentityModel.Selectors] 
FROM 'C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\System.IdentityModel.Selectors.dll'
WITH permission_set = UNSAFE
GO

-- this will add service modal
CREATE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge] 
FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication     Foundation\Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge.dll'
WITH permission_set = UNSAFE
GO
```

Comment: This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904760/deploy-failed-clr-trigger

Comment: I ran this SQL command

    `EXEC dbo.sp_changedbowner @loginame = N'sa', @map = false`

found from
    
    http://hyper-choi.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/sql-2008-calling-wcf-service-from.html

and the deployment succeeded!

Comment: Although it now deploys the client still does not work. For anyone interested I am trying a different approach:
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 2 days of trial and error, I've finally got it working, like so:

(On a **Windows Server 2008 x64, SQL Server 2008 64 bit, Assembly DLL built with Framework 3.0, Any CPU**). I suggest you stick with .Net 3 for SQL 2008.

```sql
alter database [TTBackup]
set trustworthy on;
go
USE TTBackup
--Register the assemblies referenced by our assembly.
CREATE ASSEMBLY SMdiagnostics AUTHORIZATION dbo FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\SMdiagnostics.dll' WITH permission_set = unsafe
CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.Web] AUTHORIZATION dbo FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\System.Web.dll' WITH permission_set = unsafe
CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.Runtime.Serialization] AUTHORIZATION dbo FROM 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll' WITH permission_set = unsafe
CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.IdentityModel.Selectors] FROM 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\System.IdentityModel.Selectors.dll' with permission_set = unsafe 
CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.Messaging] AUTHORIZATION dbo FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Messaging.dll' WITH permission_set = unsafe
CREATE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge] FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge.dll' with permission_set = unsafe 

--register our assembly
CREATE ASSEMBLY [TTDatabaseIntegration] AUTHORIZATION dbo FROM 'D:\TTDatabaseIntegration.dll' WITH permission_set = unsafe
GO
--Register the UDF from CLR
CREATE FUNCTION [ListImportTemplates]( ) RETURNS TABLE(TemplateID int, TemplateName NVARCHAR(4000))
AS EXTERNAL NAME [TTDatabaseIntegration].[UserDefinedFunctions].[ListImportTemplates]
GO 

--Test my function 
select  * FROM dbo.[ListImportTemplates]()
```

Notice that most of the referenced DLLs are 32 bit, but System.Web is 64 bit. (It's the only way it works for me).

#### Notes:

1. At first I've registered 64 bit assemblies, but it was throwing a runtime exception:`System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. Assembly in host store has a different signature than assembly in GAC. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131050) See Microsoft Knowledge Base article 949080 for more information.`

   I ended up comparing the files (by size) in GAC to the ones i've been registering in SQL. (GAC is located at C:\Windows\assembly, but you cannot view the folder in Explorer, I've been using [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) for this.) This is how I found that the version in GAC is the 32 bit version.
2. You can view the registered assemblies with this query: `SELECT * FROM sys.assemblies`

#### References (explaining step-by-step):

1. http://nielsb.wordpress.com/sqlclrwcf/
2. http://hyper-choi.blogspot.ro/2011/07/sql-2008-calling-wcf-service-from.html